# finding position number of an object within a list

Tags: r, list, tidyverse

I have a list as follows:

```
list(c(TRUE, FALSE), TRUE, FALSE)
```

The list contains only one object with `TRUE`, all others are a mix of `TRUE` and `FALSE`. 
I want to work out the position number of the `TRUE` only object, in this case the answer is `2`.

It sounds simple but I've failed so far.

Any ideas to solve this?

Comment: Why doesn't that first `c(TRUE, FALSE)` vector count? Are you looking for vectors that are all True, or are you *only* looking to match single `TRUE` values?

Comment: Does the `tidyverse` tag indicate that you'd like a tidyverse solution ?

Comment: @neilfws yes please

Comment: If your list is `list(c(TRUE, FALSE), c(TRUE, TRUE), FALSE))` would the answer still be 2 ?

Comment: @RonakShah there can only be one `TRUE` so it works out well

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `Position` like this:

```
L <- list(c(TRUE, FALSE), TRUE, FALSE) # test data
Position(isTRUE, L)
## [1] 2
```

Comment: The `?isTRUE` help file explains why this might be ideal for your circumstance - "*‘isTRUE(x)’ is an abbreviation of ‘identical(TRUE, x)’, and so is
     true if and only if ‘x’ is a length-one logical vector whose only
     element is ‘TRUE’ and which has no attributes (not even names).*

Answer (score 3):

In `purrr`, we can use `map_lgl`

```
lst <- list(c(TRUE, FALSE), TRUE, FALSE)
which(purrr::map_lgl(lst, all))
#[1] 2
```